# Como sincronizar o github?

Tags: git, github

Fiz umas alterações num projeto meu que estava no GitHub, agora eu quero sincronizá-lo com meu repositório local e continuar editando, como faço isso?

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Answer (score 3):

Caso não tenha clonado seu repositório remoto para sua máquina local faça no terminal o comando abaixo, no diretório em que deseja guardar

```
git clone <url do repositório remoto>
```

Caso já tenha clonado o repositório,  para puxar as alterações do remoto para o local.

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

No seu diretório local (assumindo que já tenha o mesmo projeto clonado localmente com 'git clone ') faca apenas

```
git pull
```

Este comando sincroniza o diretório local puxando tudo de novo do diretório remoto.

Caso tenha feito alterações locais que nao interessem, pode fazer

```
git stash
git pull
```

Nota: 'git stash' guarda temporariamente as alterações 'na prateleira' caso as queira usar mais tarde.

Comment: Só para complementar, quando quiser atualizar o diretório no github com as alterações entretanto feitas no seu diretório local faca: git push origin master